# How to get /allure-result (NOT allure-report) folder from junt report xml

Tags: java, junit, allure

GIVEN: Junit5 reports like:

```
  ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites>
   <testsuite name="ru.vtb.octopus.test" errors="0" skipped="0" tests="3" failures="0" time="0.10" timestamp="2021-02-1T10:23:58">
      <properties>
         <property name="vendor" value="Systems" />
         <property name="type" value="example" />
      </properties>
      <testcase classname="ru.vtb.octopus.test" name="Test1" time="0.01" />
      <testcase classname="ru.vtb.octopus.test" name="Test2" time="0.05" />
      <testcase classname="ru.vtb.octopus.test" name="Test" time="0.04" />
   </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Can I generate an /allure-result (NOT allure-report) folder.

Details:
A vendor created pl/sql autotests (non-java framework), that generates JUnit reports as a result. I can get only a result - the JUnit report.

I have to get /allure-result folder with appropriate data. This data is used as input data for another company's tool. It is possible?

It's a piece of cake to generate the final /allure-report (either using Allure CLI tool with  allure serve or allure -generate  or maven-allure plugin )

Comment: Allure has no such functionality

Comment: Thank you, Dmitry. Solved the task another way

Answer (score -1):

It's been a while but for anyone wondering, the folder allure-report is generated by the [Allure reporting](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/) tool.
To generate using maven, you can use command `mvn allure:serve`.
If you first install the [Allure commands](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_installing_a_commandline), you can use command `allure generate`.